# How can I inject a Vuetify form from a database into a template?

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuetify.js

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere, I have searched but not found anything as of yet.

I have a v-form stored in a database that I wish to pull back and display on a page. However, when I do so the form is not being rendered correctly. It remains as Vuetify template code and is not converted to HTML.

The form looks like this:

```
<v-form>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <div class="text-h4">Form 1</div>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-row>
      
      <v-col
        cols="12"
        md="6"
      >
        <v-text-field
          :counter="255"
          label="Customer ID"
          required
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-col>

      <v-col
        cols="12"
        md="6"
      >
        <v-text-field
          label="Amount"
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-col>
      <v-col class="text-right">
        <v-btn
          @click="submitForm"
        >
          Submit
        </v-btn>
      </v-col>

    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</v-form>
```

I did come across a render function, but I've either not used it correctly or it is not have the desired effect - I'm a newbie at this so it may well be something simple!

The above form is pulled back from the database using axios, and the request happens in the created() function on the page where I wish to display it, using mapGetters() to grab it from the store and v-html in a v-card to show it.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How can I inject a Vuetify form from a database into a template?*

You can't.

`v-html` [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html)

> Updates the element’s `innerHTML`. Note that the contents are inserted as plain HTML - they will not be compiled as Vue templates. If you find yourself trying to compose templates using `v-html`, try to rethink the solution by using components instead

Another [note from docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

> Note that you cannot use `v-html` to compose template partials, because Vue is not a string-based templating engine. Instead, components are preferred as the fundamental unit for UI reuse and composition.

So in short, you **cannot** insert any partial template into a template of a component at runtime.

But you can create component at runtime and use it as [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      downloadedTemplate: '<div> Hello </div>',  // pretend this was downloaded from the server
    }
  },
  computed: {
    myDynamicComponent() {
      return Vue.component('myDynamicComponent', {
        template: this.downloadedTemplate
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"> 
  <component :is="myDynamicComponent" />
</div>
```

Note that to do this, you must use Vue distribution which [includes the template compiler](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only)

I don`t know about your particular use case, but unless you are working with tens of different forms, storing templates in database sounds like a sub-optimal strategy - a lot of unnecessary work and hard to mainain

Comment: Hi Michal, thanks for your help. I had a nasty feeling that may be the case. I just ran a test copying the generated form HTML and placing that into the database instead. This partially worked, but on a page refresh the form fields mess up and overlap. Yeah I'm going to be working with a lot of user created forms, so need to store them. Looks like I'll need to build the forms in HTML from the start then.

Comment: Maybe if you describe you particular use case in more depth, we can find a better solution.

Comment: So here is the scenario: I have numerous uses who can create HTML forms from a drag and drop interface. These forms are then saved, along with some custom attributes, to a database. The forms are pulled back in an order selected by the user and filled in. Think something like CompareTheMarket for car insurance and you'll get the idea, only with custom forms created by the users, rather than the forms being a known quantity.

Comment: Ok, I would look into something called "schema based forms" libraries. Instead of saving the template itself into a DB, you save something called schema which is a "definition" of the form (what are the fields, it's data types, validations etc.). The library is then able to use that schema to create (and show) a form for you. Schema captures the essence - what is important from the data point of view. But you are still able to control the and change over time, how each input does work and how it's presented to the user.
For example: https://formvuelate.js.org/#getting-started

Comment: I came across schema based forms yesterday during my research, but I dismissed them as I assumed that they wouldn't fit my needs for a drag-drop form creator...but thinking about it, if the drag-drop interface were to create the schema in the background which is then stored in the DB, I could pull that back along with the data. Thanks for all your help Michal, much appreciated!